# Converting this particular double integral to an iterated polar

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In class, the professor converted this double integral:

$$\int_{-4}^0 \int_{-\sqrt{16-x^2}}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}} f(x,y) \,dy\,dx$$

into the following iterated polar:

$$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{4} f(r,\theta) r\,dr\,d\theta$$

My question is this: why is the outer integral for the iterated polar from $\pi$/2 to $\pi$? Shouldn't it extend from $\pi$/2 to $\frac{3{\pi}}{2}$? In other words, shouldn't the iterated polar read:

$$\int_{\pi/2}^{\frac{3{\pi}}{2}} \int_{0}^{4} f(r,\theta) r\,dr\,d\theta$$

Any insight would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Edit 1: Reformatted iterated polar to represent proper values.

Comment: You're right about the limits. I hope he didn't actually write $f(R,\theta)R\,drd\theta$! That should be $f(r,\theta)r\,drd\theta$ or $f(R,\theta)R\,dRd\theta$.

Comment: He did not! Poor formatting on my part. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right, most likely It is just a careless mistake.

The region in the quesiton describe the left part of the circle (semicircle) with center at origin with radius $4$. The $x$ value of the region is negative.

Hence, the right $\theta$ value should be from $\frac{\pi}2$ to $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: That's a relief. Thank you.